# unable to get exact height for linear layout

Tags: android, android-widget

I am having a popup window with custom layout containing list of file items. I want to set height for the popup window based on the height of the custom layout. I tried

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fileName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#303030"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newfile"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="first item"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/zw_new"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
   <View style="@style/hrView" />
   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rename"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="second item"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/zw_rename"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

style.xml

```
 <style name="hrView">
          <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
          <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
          <item name="android:background">#4f4f4f</item>
    </style>
```

Code:

```
public static PopupWindow fileMenu= null; 
    public void showfileMenu(){         
        View fileMenuView=null;

            fileMenuView =  getLayoutInflater().inflate (R.layout.zw_filemenu, null);
        fileMenuView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        int h = fileMenuView.getMeasuredHeight();
        int w = fileMenuView.getMeasuredWidth();
            fileMenu=showPopup(fileMenuView,w,h);
        }

PopupWindow pw=null;
public PopupWindow showPopup(View view,int w,int h) {
    pw = new PopupWindow(EditorActivity.getActivity());
    pw.setWidth(w);
    pw.setHeight(h);
    pw.setTouchable(true);
    pw.setFocusable(true);
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    pw.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                pw.dismiss();

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);
    pw.setContentView(view);
    return pw;

}
```

I am getting height as 106 and width as 191. Due to this, my popup window displays only first text view 'first item'(that too broken) and second item is hidden due to less height. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you create pop like

```
private PopupWindow mpopup;

View popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourxml, null); // inflating popup layout
        mpopup = new PopupWindow(popUpView, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true); // Creation of popup
        mpopup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.DialogAnimation);
        mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0); // Displaying
```

Here i m giving  `LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT`, `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`

Comment: This shows popup with full screen width. I want to show it top of a particular layout

Comment: here change mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);